# How to call a non-static method from aspx

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, ajax

I've a Method in the code behind of my aspx page, I need to call Two methods from Javascript, the problem that I'm Having is that I was trying to do it with a Json request and a WebMethod, but this method has to be static and the page components and other methods cannot be accessed from this method.

I was trying something Like:

javascript Function

```
function Func(Value) {
        var conf=confirm('Sure? '+valor)
        if (conf==true)
        {
        BlockAction();
        }
    }
       function BlockAction() {     
                 $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: 'frmVentaTelefonica.aspx/BlockAction',
                 data: "",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function (msg) {
                     $("#divResult").html("success");
                 },
                 error: function (e) {
                     $("#divResult").html("Something Wrong.");
                 }
             })};
```

Code-behind code:

```
   [WebMethod]                               
    public static  void BlockAcction()
    {
        try
        {
            frmVentaTelefonica venta = new frmVentaTelefonica();    
            venta.ConsultarVentaTelefonica();
            venta.ImprimirTiquetes();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {                
            throw;
        }
    }
```

I want to call those two methods when the confirm is true.

Update:
In need to accesses to two methods like this:

```
 public void ConsultarVentaTelefonica()
        {
            DatosImpresion = new List<Impresion>();
            IServicioVentas servicioVentas;
            servicioVentas = SATWebServiceLocator<IServicioVentas>.ObtenerServicio();
            string Tiquetes = string.Empty;
            foreach (GridDataItem dataItem in gridInfoVentaTelefonica.MasterTableView.Items)
            {
                if ((dataItem.FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox).Checked)
                {
                    Tiquetes = Tiquetes + (dataItem["Tiquete"]).Text + ",";
                }
            }
            Tiquetes = Tiquetes.TrimEnd(Tiquetes[Tiquetes.Length - 1]);
            Tiquetes = " " + Tiquetes + " ";
            DataSet dsResultado = servicioVentas.EntregaTelefonica(sessionR8A.Turno.IdTurno, Tiquetes);
            if (dsResultado.Tables.Count > 0 && dsResultado.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
```

Just run it when is true, those methods update in the database and print a ticket(first reading a grid checked items)

Comment: Please explain the problem in more detail.  Why do you need to access page components from the code behind?  What exactly are you trying to access?  Why don't you just pass whatever values you need into the BlockAction method?

Comment: MOVE FORWARD. We're in 2016. Use WebAPI!!

Comment: I know is old and really really want to update to new techs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to update the UI controls, or read their values, then what you are describing is the UpdatePanel control.  A page webmethod cannot update any control and refresh the UI (unless through JavaScript).  If you want to update the state of the page async, UpdatePanel is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying javascript just because you dont want to refresh the page, then go for Update Panel . The answer for your question is 'No' you cant access non-static methods like how you want to do.

The reason it supports only static methods is that page instantiation is not done, if you want to use non static web methods then go for web service(.asmx).